# Understanding the archive_cleanup_command

Tags: postgresql

In the postgresql.conf file for PostgreSQL version 13, the archive_cleanup_command comment explains the command in the following way:

> #archive_cleanup_command = ''         # command to execute at every restartpoint.

The documentation [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/pgarchivecleanup.html) and [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/continuous-archiving.html) have no mention of a 'restartpoint'. This raises the following questions:

1. **What is a restartpoint?**
   For example: is restartpoint just the same word for a checkpoint? Do the two mean the exact same thing?
2. **When is a restartpoint created?**
   For example: if the restartpoint is just a checkpoint then the check point will be created every 5mins or whatever the setting for checkpoint_timeout is in postgresql.conf file.
3. **When is the archive cleanup command run?**
   For example: The archive cleanup command is run every time the archive_timeout (set in the postgresql.conf file) is reached. If the archive timeout is set to 1hr, then the archive_cleanup_command runs every 1hr.

Comment: Please do [not crosspost](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/157328). Already asked and answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64853245

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's cross-posted and answered elsewhere

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Apologies, I wasn't aware that cross posting isn't allowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good way to find such information is to go to the [index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/bookindex.html) of the manual and look for "restartpoint". Which indeed is listed there and leads to [WAL configuration](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/wal-configuration.html)

> In archive recovery or standby mode, the server periodically performs restartpoints, which are similar to checkpoints in normal operation: the server forces all its state to disk, updates the pg_control file to indicate that the already-processed WAL data need not be scanned again, and then recycles any old log segment files in the pg_wal directory. Restartpoints can't be performed more frequently than checkpoints in the master because restartpoints can only be performed at checkpoint records. A restartpoint is triggered when a checkpoint record is reached if at least checkpoint_timeout seconds have passed since the last restartpoint, or if WAL size is about to exceed max_wal_size. However, because of limitations on when a restartpoint can be performed, max_wal_size is often exceeded during recovery, by up to one checkpoint cycle's worth of WAL. (max_wal_size is never a hard limit anyway, so you should always leave plenty of headroom to avoid running out of disk space.)

Comment: Thank you so much for the index page link!!! Teach a man how to fish vs giving me a fish! That's awesome! Thank you so much!!!

Comment: For PG v16 this option is described [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/runtime-config-wal.html)